# How many times to use 'Call doc.save(True, False) in a code?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Im coding an agent in Lotus Script. The code looks like this:

```
Sub Initialize
    ' * Some more code *
    Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("form_Initialize_Status01", "Command 1 successful run.")
    Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("form_Initialize_Status02", "Command 2 successful run.")
    ' * Some more code *

    Call Sub_Action()

    ' * Some more code *
    Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("form_Initialize_Status03", "Command 3 successful run.")
End Sub


Sub Sub_Action()
    ' * Some more code *
    Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("form_Sub_Action_Status01", "Command 1 successful run.")
    ' * Some more code *
    Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("form_Sub_Action_Status02", "Command 2 successful run.")
End Sub
```

**Question:**

What is the recommanded way to put the following line to save the document?:

> Call doc.save(True, False)

After each `Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue` or only once in the end of the Sub?

Comment: Once you have all items set at the end of your code

Comment: And if you don't use the item you could just use "call doc.ReplaceItemvalue(...)"

Comment: OK, that means that `call doc.ReplaceItemValue` does save the doc after he is doing that replacement of the item value?

Comment: no. call doc.ReplaceItemValue replaces the item value in the doc object in memory. If you want to save the changes back to the disk/db you need to call doc.save(true,false) after your last change.

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR: Only save ONCE at the end.

There are several things to consider here:

First of all: ReplaceItemValue- operations are purely modifications to the document in memory. They do not trigger any database operations (aka disk writes). 
The "Save"- Operation on the other hand DOES trigger database operations. 
Even without considering the performance impact this should be reason enough to save as economical as possible.

But now lets additionally consider the side- effects of a solution that saves after every change of an item:

Your code might transfer a document from one state to the other. To completely achieve this transfer, ususally ALL items need to be changed to their new state in the document.

Code is NEVER 100% bug free. And even if it is: The code can fail for whatever reason in the middle of execution.

Whatever the reason is for your code stopping after the first 5 items: If you save every single change, then your document will be in an inconsistent state and you need to write code to rollback the changes or start where the code left and complete the changes.

Better do ALL your transofrmations and then save at the very end, when everything is done and consistent.

One exception for this is writing log- documents where you add the progress adding lines to the log. If you want to observe the progress from another place, then saving after every log- entry- line would be the right thing to do. But there are not much other scenarios where this would be true.

Comment: Also, an incomplete/inconsistent document could end up being replicated to other servers, and may exist on those other servers in that inconsistent state for hours after your code has finished -- until the next replication cycle comes around!

Comment: Although Notes is not 'transactional' - you can think of 'doc.save' as a one-off 'commit' operation, changing the data on document from 'State-A' to 'State-B' in one go. Skipping the save is equivalent to 'rollback'.